# making more than one pdf document in java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

This is my code:

```
try { 
        dozen = magazijn.getFfd().vraagDozenOp();
        for (int i = 0; i < dozen.size(); i++) { 
            PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("Order" + x + ".pdf"));
            System.out.println("Writer instance created");
            doc.open(); 
            System.out.println("doc open"); 
            Paragraph ordernummer = new Paragraph(order.getOrdernummer()); 
            doc.add(ordernummer); 
            doc.add( Chunk.NEWLINE );
            for (String t : text) { 
                Paragraph klant = new Paragraph(t);
                doc.add(klant); 
            } 
            doc.add( Chunk.NEWLINE );
            Paragraph datum = new Paragraph (order.getDatum());
            doc.add(datum);
            doc.add( Chunk.NEWLINE );
            artikelen = magazijn.getFfd().vraagArtikelenOp(i);
            for (Artikel a : artikelen){
                artikelnr.add(a.getArtikelNaam());
            }
            for (String nr: artikelnr){
                Paragraph Artikelnr = new Paragraph(nr);
                doc.add(Artikelnr);
            }

            doc.close(); 
            artikelnr.clear(); 
            x++; 
            System.out.println("doc closed"); 
        }

    } catch (Exception e) { 
        System.out.println(e); 
    }
```

I get this exception: com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: The document has been closed. You can't add any Elements.

can someone help me fix this so that the other pdf can be created and paragrphs added?

Comment: so what is `x` ? Obviously, you need to create a fresh `doc` for each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, your intent is not very clear from your code and question so I'm going to operate under the following assumptions:

1. You are creating a report for each box you're processing
2. Each report needs to be a separate PDF file

You're getting a `DocumentException` on the second iteration of the loop, you're trying to add content to a Document that has been closed in the previous iteration via  `doc.close();`. 'doc.close' will finalize the `Document` and write everything still pending to any linked `PdfWriter`.

If you wish to create separate pdfs for each box, you need to create a seperate `Document` in your loop statement as well, since creating a new `PdfWriter` via `PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("Order" + x + ".pdf"));` will not create a new `Document` on its own.

If I'm wrong with assumption 2 and you wish to add everything to a single PDF, move `doc.close();` outside of the loop and create only a single `PdfWriter`

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this using Apache PDFBox

```
File outputFile = new File(path);
outputFile.createNewFile();
PDDocument newDoc = new PDDocument();
```

then create a `PDPage` and write what you wanna write in that page. After your page is ready, add it to the `newDoc` and in the end save it and close it

```
newDoc.save(outputFile);
```

`newDoc.close()`

repeat this `dozen.size()` times and keep changing the file's name in `path` for every new document.

Comment: You'd dump everything in one document then, and create X copies of this document as well. It's not immediately clear that this would be desired or undesired behaviour, but you should at least put a warning for this in your answer. I'm going to downvote until something like this is added.

Comment: @SamuelHuylebroeck You are right. Well I am not very familiar with itext. So, I've changed my answer.

Comment: Your answer now does not make any sense. You compare two classes from distinct PDF libraries which have completely different roles in the respective architecture, but you expect them to operate similarly just because their names are similar.

Comment: @mkl I think I've left the things ambiguous here. I just wanted to propose a solution by using ONLY PDFBox as an alternative.

Comment: Recommending the use of a different library nowadays is usually considered bad style on stack overflow. Only if the library in question cannot be used at all for the task at hand, that might be viable. And it is trivial to *"make more than one pdf document"* using iText; @Samuel in his answer has given appropriate hints. Unfortunately the OP has not yet reacted in any way to say whether that answer helped.

Comment: @mkl Forgive me, Father, for I have sinned